# Custom exception with additional properties?

Tags: oop, exception

I hope there is a clear answer to this question.

**Is it preferable to extend a custom exception with additional properties, like an item ID or something similar, to allow the exception to be analysed by the receiving client?**

The alternative would be to have all the valuable information hidden in the message string. Or to replace the exception by a complex return value with the actual result and the additional context information, which would have been in the exception's properties otherwise.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Maybe both. Extended properties are good for parsing the exception. The string representation with as much info as possible might be still useful for human reading when caught by an external tool (e.g. testing) that cannot get the information out of the custom properties.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the scenario. Usually if that's an actual exception (something that stops the method being executed) I would use the first option of extending the exception class.

The string option sounds bad, no matter what the scenario is.

The complex return object sounds good to me when we talk about things like responses (for example - HttpResponse) where you have different layers of problems that can happen (is the exception thrown due to no communication? Maybe credentials error? Or an actual logic exception on the server side?).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Any other thoughts?